# dynamic select boxes related to one other in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp, jstl

I have two lists like department and manager and i put these two in request scope.
Now I want to show the two lists in the select boxes such that when the user select one department the corresponding manager should come in the next select box as default. And if i want to change the manager i can choose any other and save.

My jsp is like this.
the first select box which has departments.

```
<select id="dname" name="Name" onchange="autoPopulateModifydept();">
       <option value="">-Select</option>
       <c:forEach var="departmentList" items="${departmentList}">
           <option value='${departmentList.getDepartment()}@${departmentList.getId()}'>${departmentList.getDepartment()}</option>
       </c:forEach>
</select>
```

The second select box which has managerlist.

```
<select  id="deptHead" name="deptHead" onchange="autoPopulatedeptHead();">
       <option value="">-Select-</option>
            <c:forEach var="projectmanager" items="${projectManagerList}">
            <option value='${projectmanager.getProjectManagerName()}@${projectmanager.getPmId()}'>${projectmanager.getProjectManagerName()}</option>
            </c:forEach>
</select>
```

here getId in department and getPmId in manager are same.
Based on that I want to link the two select boxes.
How to do that.

Comment: more details: is the manager of each department stocked in department objects ? Or do you need server calls to get manager of selected department ?

Comment: the department and the manager lists have one common property id. based on that the comparison should happen.

Comment: user select one department. That means one the corresponding id will be picked. based on that the manager should be appear in the manager select box which matches to the manager id.

Comment: can anybody answer plz???

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using javascript, Please see the sample example below. call this method on change of first list selection and compare the selected value of first list with second list and make second list selected with matching first list Id value.

```
function changeMangerId(){ 
var emplId =document.getElementById("firstList").value;
<c:forEach var="paramObj"
    items="${managerList}]
var managerIdId= '<c:out value="${Id}"/>';
             if(emplId)!= null && (emplId)!= '' && trim(emplId)=== trimm(anagerIdId) {
                 $("#SecondListId option[value='"+ managerIdId +"']").attr("selected", "selected");
          }
</c:forEach>
}
```